# How to prove that a poll with 2 mutually-exclusive options converges faster than one with 3 or more answers

Tags: statistical-significance, python, inference, survey, scipy

**Disclaimer**:
I am kind of new to the survey analysis field, and I am pretty sure that I lack some key concepts and their namings.

I will try to be clear as much as I can. I hope someone could be of help.
Thanks in advance.

**Problem statement**:
Let us say that I am running 2 different surveys:

- survey 1 asks "which city would you prefer to live in?", and has 2 mutually answers (Berlin, Paris).
- survey 2 asks the same question, and has 3 mutually exclusive (Berlin, Paris, London).

**Questions**:
Assuming that the 2 surveys would be addressed to the same crowd, chosen by random-sampling,

1- I imagine that the population proportion of 'Paris' would converge (increase in statistical relevance) faster than survey 2, because of the higher number of answers in the latter. Is this correct? how can I prove it?

2- Which kpi (e.g. margin of error of population proportion, Chi-squared test, etc.) can I use in order to find out how many total collected responses would be enough before stopping both surveys 1 and 2?

**What I tried**:

Confidence level considered = 80%

So far, I tried to calculate the population proportion margin of error of Paris using the following code, inspired by [this link](https://regenerativetoday.com/a-complete-guide-to-confidence-interval-and-calculation-in-python/):

```
    import scipy import stats

    confidence_level = 0.8
    number_of_answers = 80

    # adjusting the confidence for a 2-sided student T distribution:
    q = confidence_level + (1 - confidence_level) / 2

    t_critical = stats.t.ppf(q=q, df=number_of_answers - 1)

    paris_population_proportion = 0.434

    margin_of_error = t_critical * np.sqrt(
            paris_population_proportion
            * (1 - paris_population_proportion)
            / number_of_answers
    )
```

However, this margin of error does not take into consideration how many mutually exclusive answers reside in the survey being analyzed, and would thus give similar results in both cases.

I hope this makes some sense.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: (1) Why would Survey 2 have more answers than Survey 1?? (2) What do you mean by "statistical relevance"?  (3) Why do you suppose the answers would actually differ?  What if nobody prefers London, for instance?  (4) What is your criterion for stopping the surveys?

Comment: @whuber 
(1) I saw several surveys having different numbers of answers like that, and it made me wonder if the number of answers in a survey affects the number of required answers to collect.

(2) What I mean is that X number of collected answers would be enough to represent the population.

(3) You have a point here. So let us assume we would actually have some who would opt for London.

(4) I was thinking of using the margin of error. But I do not think it reflects the number of answers in the survey. Can you suggest a better criterion?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: When you plan a one-shot survey and wish to determine a suitable sample size, you have to specify (among other things) (a) what estimates you will make from the survey and (b) how precise you will need those estimates to be.  When you contemplate two different sets of survey questions, this brings (a) to the fore: how exactly are the two sets of questions related and how does each address the intended estimates?  Only then can you hope to compare the two designs and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

From your code and browsing the link, I think maybe by 'converge' you mean to have a CI with a small margin of error. In large part, the answer depends on the proportions of people liking various cities under the two scenarios.

Roughly, the formula for the sample size $n$ necessary to get a suitably small margin of error $E$ (half the width of the CI) in a 95% CI is
$n \approx 4p(1-p)/E^2,$ where $p$ is the success
probability.

With Berlin vs. Paris, if you got a 50-50 split
so that the proportion favoring Paris is $p = 1/2,$ then you need $n = 2500$ subjects to get a margin of error of $E = 0.02.$

Among three cities you might still have half favoring Paris. and the CI for Paris would still have $E = 0.02$ with $n=2500$ subjects. [Using R as a calculator.]

```
4*.5*.5/(.02)^2
[1] 2500
```

However, if the three-way choice has three equally favored cities, then $p = P(\mathrm{Paris}) = 1/3$ and the number of subjects altogether to get $E = 0.02$ would be only about $n = 2200.$

```
4*.33*.67/(.02)^2
[1] 2211
```

The probability $p$ that requires the most subjects to estimate within a given margin of error is $p=1/2.$

[image]

```
p = seq(0, 1, by = .01)
n = 4*p*(1-p)/.02^2
hdr="Nr. of Subjects for 95% CI with E=0.02"
plot(p, n, type="l", main=hdr)
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=0:1, col="green2")
```

Comment: Thank you @BruceET for your answer.
can you please share the source of this equation?  95% CI is ≈4(1−)/2
what if I choose a different CI?

Comment: Wald 95% CI for binomial success probability is $\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}}$ Given margin of error, solve for $n$ using 1.96 \approx 2 and $\hat  p \approx p,$ Formula given in many elementary textbooks.